# Separating Axis Theorem - Containment and the minimum translation vector

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection

My code to calculate the minimum translation vector using the Separating Axis Theorem works perfectly well, except when one of the polygons is completely contained by another polygon. I have scoured the internet for the solution to this problem and everyone just seems to ignore it ( http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55#sat-contain talks about this, but doesn't give a full solution...)

The pictures below is a screenshot from my program illustrating the problem. The translucent blue triangle is the position of the rectangle before the MTV is applied, and the other triangle is with the MTV applied.

[image: MTV Containment Problem - Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the link you shared does give a solution to this. In your MTV calculation, you have to test for complete containment in a projection and change the calculations accordingly. (The pseudocode is in reference to figure 9 on that page.) Perhaps if you post your code, we can comment on why it isn't working.